# Нужно ли ставить тире перед "Вы"?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить тире в следующем предложении "Теперь Вы – член сообщества единомышленников, объединенных идеей здорового образа жизни".

И вообще, нужно ли ставить тире, в таких предложениях, как "Вы пенсионер", "Я учитель" и др.

Answer (score 3):

Если подлежащее выражено местоимением, а сказуемое существительным, то тире не ставится. Но если это какой-то авторский знак, то ставится.

Comment: То есть в принципе можно и оставить в данном контексте тире или лучше убрать?

Comment: В данном контексте можно оставить тире как авторский знак, усилив паузой ВЫ. Но если при чтении паузы нет - тире не нужно ( в соответствии с правилами)

Answer (score 0):

Хочу также добавить, что в разговорных предложениях тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, коль подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое - существительным в И.п.

Пример: "Моя мама бухгалтер".

Comment: Здесь подлежащее - мама, а(чья?)МОЯ- определение. Пример неудачный.